# Displaying photos in "years, collections, moments" structure?

Tags: camera, photos, android-versions, album-art

Since iOS7 the photos has been organized by time and location and I find it quite handy to find photos, however when I switch to Android it's quite a painful experience to find photos. Is there any way to achieve the similar?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I didn't find any Android phone that does similar thing. However if you are OK with 3rd-party albums, here's one that seems to do exactly what you want. It's not as fast as iPhone but the performance is quite acceptable.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.atomicadd.fotos

[image]